# error Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" and SQL Server Data Tools Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have a SSIS package for getting data from a webservice and insert to the SQL Server(using OLEDB connection with sql user and mu protection level is a EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey).

but I would like to add the agent job on SQL Ad-hoc server by using a filesystem package source.

So, the job agent will execute on SQL Ad-Hoc Server but inside a package will getting data from a webservice and import to another server.

I found error when I execute agent job on SQL SERVER like this:

#

Code: 0xC0016016     Source: trade0010_gg      Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password"
 with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized
 to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. 
 Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error: 2018-07-10 02:12:22.33

---

Code: 0xC000F427     Source: Web Service Task      Description: To run a SSIS package outside
 of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.
 End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  2:12:20 AM
 Finished: 2:12:22 AM  Elapsed:  1.625 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

#

I'm not sure that is a EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey issue or a Data tool Edition issue? because I test another package it's just only insert csv to SQL SERVER Destination by using a agent job(filesystem package source) on SQL Server Ad-hoc and it works.

My Ad-hoc SQL SERVER is SQL SERVER 2017 and Data tool 2017 also.
My Destination SQL SERVER is SQL SERVER 2016 and DATA tool 2012.

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which error is the issue either, but here is how to deal with them:

**EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey**: A way to avoid a lot of headaches with sensitive data is to change the encryption level to *Don't save sensitive*.  Then, in SQL Agent, configure the passwords for your connections.

**Edition of Integration Services**: Make sure that you have standard or enterprise edition installed on the adhoc server (the one that is executing the package via SQL Agent).

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, standard or enterprise edition that mean the edition for SQL SERVER right?

Comment: Standard and enterprise are editions. That’s correct